# JAVA + Hibernate: ORA-01407 when updating not null value

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

Here is my *OrderNames* pojo class mapping:

```
...

<cache usage="transactional"/>

<id name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
    <column name="ID" precision="19" scale="0" />
    <generator class="sequence">
        <param name="sequence_name">MY_SEQ</param>
    </generator>
</id>

<property name="orderId" type="java.lang.Long">
    <column name="ORDER_ID" precision="19" scale="0" not-null="true"/>
</property>

<property name="userId" type="java.lang.Long">
    <column name="USER_ID" precision="19" scale="0" not-null="true"/>
</property>

<property name="orderName" type="java.lang.String">
    <column name="ORDER_NAME" length="35" not-null="true"/>
</property>

...
```

Here is my pojo class:

```
public class OrderNamesModel {

    private Long id;
    private Long orderId;
    private Long userId;
    private String orderName;

    public String getOrderName() {
        return orderName;
    }

    public void setOrderName(String orderName) {
        this.orderName = orderName;
    }

    public Long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public Long getOrderId() {
        return orderId;
    }

    public void setOrderId(Long orderId) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

And my code:

```
public void changeOrderName(Long orderId, Long userId, String orderName) {
    OrderModel orderModel = getOrderModelForUpdate(orderId, userId, orderName);
    ordersDAO.saveOrder(orderModel);
}

private OrderModel getOrderModelForUpdate(Long orderId, Long userId, String orderName){
    OrderModel orderModel = ordersDAO.get(orderId);
    OrderNamesModel orderNameModel = ordersDAO.getByIdAndUserId(orderId, userId);
    orderName = StringUtils.trimToEmpty(orderName);
    if(StringUtils.isBlank(orderName)){
        orderModel.setOrderNames(null);
    }
    else{
        if(orderNameModel == null){
            orderNameModel = new OrderNamesModel();
            orderNameModel.setOrderId(orderModel.getOrderId());
            orderNameModel.setUserId(userId);
        }
        orderNameModel.setOrderName(orderName);
        orderModel.setOrderNames(new HashSet<>(Collections.singletonList(orderNameModel)));
    }

    return orderModel;
}
```

After launching it with orderName = "New order Name", I get existing row from DB and exception occurs on performng save:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01407: cant update
>   ("MY_DB"."ORDER_NAMES"."ORDER_ID") to NULL

In debug mode value of orderId is set in OrderNamesModel to 123

What could cause such strange problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have this property:

> ```
> <property name="orderName" type="java.lang.String">
>     <column name="ORDER_NAME" length="35" not-null="true"/>
> </property>
> ```

which states that the `ORDER_NAME` is `NOT NULL` (which I am assuming maps directly to a `NOT NULL` constraint on the underlying table.

In your `getOrderModelForUpdate` function, you are then doing:

> ```
> orderModel.setOrderNames(null);
> ```

this, given the name of the function, then gets used to perform an update and is trying to set a `NOT NULL` property to `NULL` and getting the error

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01407: cant update ("MY_DB"."ORDER_NAMES"."ORDER_ID") to NULL

This would seem to be an entirely appropriate error when you try to set a `NOT NULL` column to have a `NULL` value.

If you should be able to have `NULL` values in the column (and an empty string is the same as a `NULL` in Oracle) then you need to drop the `NOT NULL` constraint on the table. Conversely, if your table constraints are correct then you can't set the value to `NULL` and should pick another value.